# change a range of colors to white in python

Tags: python, image-processing

I use following code to change specific colors (grays) to white in photos. But the code is too slow. any suggestion or alternative is welcomed.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
for j in range(1,160):
    im = Image.open(str(j)+'.jpg')
    data = np.array(im)
    for i in (range(205,254)):
        r1, g1, b1 = i, i, i # Original 
        r2, g2, b2 = 255, 255, 255 # Replacement

        red, green, blue = data[:,:,0], data[:,:,1], data[:,:,2]
        mask = (red == r1) & (green == g1) & (blue == b1)
        data[:,:,:3][mask] = [r2, g2, b2]

        im = Image.fromarray(data)
        im.save(os.getcwd()+'\\conv\\'+str(j)+'.jpg')
```

Comment: If you want to do image manipulation in a faster manner you should use GPU for it and using OpenCV instead of PIL (in a proper way) might influence performance as well, as PIL is rather high level. This might be useful: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing an indent at the end, you're saving each output image 50 times. I changed your code to be:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

for j in range(0, 10):
    filename = f'{str(j)}.jpg'
    print(f'processing {filename} ...')

    im = Image.open(filename) 
    data = np.array(im)
    for i in range(205, 254):
        r1, g1, b1 = i, i, i # Original 
        r2, g2, b2 = 255, 255, 255 # Replacement

        red, green, blue = data[:,:,0], data[:,:,1], data[:,:,2]
        mask = (red == r1) & (green == g1) & (blue == b1)
        data[:,:,:3][mask] = [r2, g2, b2]

    im = Image.fromarray(data)
    im.save(f'x_{filename}')
```

160 took too long for testing, so I just tried with 10 images. On my laptop with a 6k x 4k jpg image I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ../grey.py 
processing 0.jpg ...
processing 8.jpg ...
processing 9.jpg ...
435588:70.75
```

So 70.8s and 436MB of memory.

I rewrote your program using [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/). It's usually [much faster than PIL, numpy or opencv](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use) at this kind of thing. The pyvips version looks like:

```
import pyvips

for j in range(0, 10):
    filename = f'{str(j)}.jpg'
    print(f'processing {filename} ...')

    im = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(filename, access='sequential')

    # find all pixels where RGB are equal
    mask = (im[0] == im[1]) & (im[1] == im[2])

    # we also need g > 204 
    mask &= im[1] > 204

    # and send all those pixels to 255
    im = mask.ifthenelse(255, im)

    im.write_to_file(f'x_{filename}')
```

On my laptop I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ../grey-vips.py 
processing 0.jpg ...
...
processing 8.jpg ...
processing 9.jpg ...
152084:4.87
```

4.9s and 152MB of memory.

Of course that's a bit unfair. As Amitay says, your code is looping rather than masking a range, but I don't know numpy well enough to fix that.

Comment: This is about 4 times faster than my own code for 40 pics in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This way of image processing is slow because it is single threaded, and straightforward. Try splitting it into multiple equal parts, and running them at the same time for a major speedup (try to split the job with function and check the results: more of smaller chunks vs lesser number of larger ones).
For greater improvement: GPU supported image manipulating, but it's quite hard in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for all the values in the image were all thae values of all channels are the same. Therefore first create a mask for all the pixels that are equal for all three channels and than from them only leave the ones that are in your range.
Try the following code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
for j in range(1,160):
    im = Image.open(str(j)+'.jpg')
    data = np.array(im)
    for i in (range(205,254)):
        r1, g1, b1 = i, i, i # Original 
        r2, g2, b2 = 255, 255, 255 # Replacement

        red, green, blue = data[:,:,0], data[:,:,1], data[:,:,2]
        maskEqualValues = (red==green) & (red==blue) & (green==blue)
        maskEqualValuesVal = np.multiply(maskEqualValues,red);
        mask = (maskEqualValuesVal > 205) & (maskEqualValuesVal <= 254)

        im = Image.fromarray(data)
        im.save(os.getcwd()+'\\conv\\'+str(j)+'.jpg')
```